# Text File to Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Good evening, I have a text file that has letters, floats and ints such as this:

p 0 0 
 p 1 0 
 p .5 1 
 p .1 2 
 f 3 1 2 
 f 2 1 4

 f 4 1 3 
 w -20.0 -20.0 20 20

So basically:
 
 p = points(x,y) 
 f = faces so f 4 1 3 means connect p4 p1 and p3 by creating lines between these points to create a figure

 w = window size on my canvas through tkinter

I'm attempting to read in the text file to an array through numpy by using:

```
np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=' ', dtype=None)
```

but I keep getting a ValueError: got 3 columns instead of 2

At this point, is there a way to store all of the data into an array ?
Or should I store them into separate lists by p, f, and w and then converting those lists into pArray, fArray, and wArray ? And then connecting the points by drawing lines using these different arrays ?

Comment: You can't have an np.array with rows of different lengths. So either use different arrays (what I would recommend) or manually pad with dummy values if you absolutely want a single array.

Comment: Would you recommend I use lists or tuples to parse data ?

Comment: tuples are non mutable, so you can't grow them as you go, lists seem like a better option.

Comment: It should be simpler to read the lines yourself, `split()` and collect related values into a lists (of lists).  Create separate p, f, and w array, with sizes of (4,2), (3,3), (3,) respectively.